# C++11 "In class initialization" feature is not working for unions

Tags: c++, c++11, unions, in-class-initialization

Minimal code example:

```
struct B { 
  union U {
    struct S {} s;
    int i = 100;
  }
  u;  
};
```

Now if we declare a `B obj;` then the `obj.u.i` is assigned a garbage value instead of `100`.   See the [demo here](http://ideone.com/0213tb). (The garbage value differs based on optimization flags etc.).

Is the "In class initialization" feature supposed to work with unions.

- If yes, then what is the correct syntax? Or is this a g++ bug?
- If not then what `int i = 100;` does?

Comment: [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6ab1a0f46b2229dfc46dfa6f4f5e3163-6e9f1f680880347f6708b805c806db62) seems happy with your code.

Comment: @Praetorian, Thanks. However, you haven't put the output statements. So here is the correct [clang output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=542928082d0e3f7d6edd525a7fcfac44-6e9f1f680880347f6708b805c806db62).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a GCC bug. The standard says (9.5p2):

> At most one non-static data member of a union may have a *brace-or-equal-initializer*.

Otherwise, the rules are the same as for a regular class.

EDIT: In addition, 12.6.2p8:

> In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or
>   base class is not designated by a *mem-initializer-id* (including the
>   case where there is no
>   *mem-initializer-list* because the constructor has no *ctor-initializer*) and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> - if the entity is a non-static data member that has a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, the entity is initialized as specified in 8.5;
> - otherwise, if the entity is a variant member (9.5), no initialization is performed;
> - otherwise, the entity is default-initialized (8.5).

Presumably the implicitly defined default constructor counts here. The `i` member meets the criteria in the first bullet point, so it's initialized like it were a regular class member. The `s` member matches the second bullet point, so it's left uninitialized.

Comment: It does not compile on VS 2010 & 2012, not even the first version, with the error: only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class. Or both compilers have a bug or there is something more...

Comment: @neagoegab Neither of those VS versions support in-class initialization of data members. [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6ab1a0f46b2229dfc46dfa6f4f5e3163-6e9f1f680880347f6708b805c806db62) is compiling the code with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is like that because a union reunites more than one element. Below is the work around syntax:

```
struct B { 
  union U {
    int i;
  }
  u {100};  
};

int main () {
  B obj;
  std::cout << "obj.u.i = " << obj.u.i << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Please stop guessing. Post an answer which you *know*, and can suppport.

Comment: @Nawaz, I belive that I have supported my answer. The alternative is to find it in the standard, but at that you are faster than me :D, but I will update the answer.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with my actual problem, just add `struct S {} s;` inside the `union U` and the program gives [compiler error](http://ideone.com/5tS7q9). I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @iammilind The workaround is to define a default constructor for `U`: `U() : i(100) {}` instead of using in-class member initialization.